Creating an event for Lead in salesforce
I am creating an integration with salesforce where in I pass all the leads that come on my platform to salesforce programatically using Salesforce REST API
.../services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/

Now i want to pass events related to this lead(page visited, demo_scheduled...) to salesforce too. Upon getting this lead we want to create workflows in salesforce like send internal email, notifying leads etc. Is there an "events of lead" concept in salesforce. What will be endpoint to achieve this?
